# Cards granting emblems

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-emblems

Are there any spells (sorceries, instants) that grant emblems? The only way to get an emblem that I've seen so far is for a planeswalker's ability to grant an emblem. I wonder if there is any other spell that can be cast to receive an emblem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[No](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3Aemblem+-t%3Aplaneswalker), not at this time.

- `o:emblem` means the Oracle text (rules text) of the card must include the word "Emblem".
- `-t:planeswalker` means the card must not have the type "Planeswalker".

The [18 cards](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3Aemblem&v=list&s=cname) that do mention "Emblem" are all Planeswalkers.

Comment: I'll take that answer, but how do you know?

Comment: Did you follow the link?

Comment: This answer is technically still accurate, but could probably use an update to account for new cards (found at the links you already provide). The second link lists several non-planeswalker cards now, but they're all DFCs with planeswalkers on their back that actually create the emblems. The first link now goes to Teferi's Talent, which is an enchantment that *defines* an emblem but only lets a planeswalker create it; a near miss in my opinion.

Comment: In addition to that, the new keyword action "the Ring tempts you" creates an emblem called The Ring. As a result, a number of non-planeswalker cards now create that emblem.

Answer (score 5):

While not strictly speaking emblems, there *are* non-Planeswalker cards which create effects with durations of "for the rest of the game," which is the *original* wording for [Elspeth, Knight Errant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?printed=true&multiverseid=174859) (before she was errataed to have an emblem).

[Cyclopean Tomb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cyclopean%20Tomb) removes mire counters that it put onto a land each turn for the rest of the game after it leaves the battlefield.

[Praetor's Counsel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Praetor%27s%20Counsel) gives you no maximum hand size for the rest of the game.

[Stigma Lasher](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stigma%20Lasher) prevents a player from gaining life for the rest of the game.

The Epic ability from Saviors of Kamigawa prevents you from casting additional spells for the rest of the game. ([Enduring Ideal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Enduring%20Ideal), [Eternal Dominion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Eternal%20Dominion), [Neverending Torment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Neverending%20Torment), [Undying Flames](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Undying%20Flames), [Endless Swarm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Endless%20Swarm))

Answer (score 2):

### Planeswalkers are the only sources of emblems

Mark Rosewater, the Head Designer for Magic, has said [on his Tumblr blog](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/128602183048/could-there-ever-be-a-non-planeswalker-card-that) that

> We have chosen to make emblems a planeswalker-only thing.

That is one of [many](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/search/emblem) answers Mark has given regarding emblems, stretching at least as far back as 2011, and continuing to the present day, where Ascend (which is a "for the rest of the game" mechanic which could have been designed using emblems) has prompted questions about the issue again.  All of them say basically the same thing.

WotC could, of course, change this decision and decide to let non-Planeswalker cards create emblems.  But they have so far shown no signs of being interested in doing so.

That said, until any cards are printed which interact with emblems in any way, effects which last "for the rest of the game" are functionally equivalent to emblems, and those do exist on a number of different card types.  The distinction that makes one of these effects an emblem has far more flavor significance than it does mechanical significance.

Special mention goes to [Obsidian Fireheart](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=430594), the card that held the title for "Greatest Reminder Text" ("The land continues to burn after Obsidian Fireheart has left the battlefield") until the Unstable card [Gimme Five](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439396) stole that title with "Offer high fives.  Don't hit people."

Comment: No longer accurate - "The Ring" is an emblem and is granted by the "The Ring Tempts You" mechanic that appears on non-planeswalker cards

Answer (score 1):

As of today (Dec 24, 2014) there are 18 cards with Oracle wording that gives an emblem. As you can see, they are all Planeswalkers.

(source: [this search here](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?output=compact&text=%20%5Bemblem%5D) - I've cleaned up some un-necessary details for readability)

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| [Ajani Steadfast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ajani%20Steadfast) | Planeswalker — Ajani |
| [Dack Fayden](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dack%20Fayden) | Planeswalker — Dack |
| [Daretti, Scrap Savant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Daretti%2C%20Scrap%20Savant) | Planeswalker — Daretti |
| [Domri Rade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Domri%20Rade) | Planeswalker — Domri |
| [Elspeth, Knight-Errant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elspeth%2C%20Knight-Errant) | Planeswalker — Elspeth |
| [Elspeth, Sun's Champion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elspeth%2C%20Sun%27s%20Champion) | Planeswalker — Elspeth |
| [Garruk, Apex Predator](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Garruk%2C%20Apex%20Predator) | Planeswalker — Garruk |
| [Garruk, Caller of Beasts](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Garruk%2C%20Caller%20of%20Beasts) | Planeswalker — Garruk |
| [Kiora, the Crashing Wave](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kiora%2C%20the%20Crashing%20Wave) | Planeswalker — Kiora |
| [Koth of the Hammer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Koth%20of%20the%20Hammer) | Planeswalker — Koth |
| [Liliana of the Dark Realms](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Liliana%20of%20the%20Dark%20Realms) | Planeswalker — Liliana |
| [Ob Nixilis of the Black Oath](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ob%20Nixilis%20of%20the%20Black%20Oath) | Planeswalker — Nixilis |
| [Sarkhan, the Dragonspeaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sarkhan%2C%20the%20Dragonspeaker) | Planeswalker — Sarkhan |
| [Sorin, Lord of Innistrad](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sorin%2C%20Lord%20of%20Innistrad) | Planeswalker — Sorin |
| [Sorin, Solemn Visitor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sorin%2C%20Solemn%20Visitor) | Planeswalker — Sorin |
| [Tamiyo, the Moon Sage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tamiyo%2C%20the%20Moon%20Sage) | Planeswalker — Tamiyo |
| [Teferi, Temporal Archmage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Teferi%2C%20Temporal%20Archmage) | Planeswalker — Teferi |
| [Venser, the Sojourner](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Venser%2C%20the%20Sojourner) | Planeswalker — Venser |